# Undefined Variable PHP_SELF

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am developing a backend with php here.

I am having problem with such error like this:

> Undefined variable : PHP_SELF

on my htdocs directory.

I'm developing with php 5.4.4 , and if you want to look at the source code here it is:

http://pastebin.com/xr2PxbNG

Comment: Were you actually looking for $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?

Comment: I am building them in my localhost. Let me change them for a moment :)

Comment: @FirmView I would not suggest that.

Comment: @FirmView: Nah, we don't do that anymore. While the associated problems mainly arise from running all other code in global scope as well, it's best for newcomers to eschew that feature.

Comment: yeah, i know that, he is saying that, he is using localhost.  So he will know why exactly its not working for him.  Let him understand the settings

Comment: And here goes `register_global_variables` :)

Comment: all of the suggestionn really help me, I declare php_self = $PHP_SELF = &$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

new error come to unexpected 'border' on line 155 zzz

Comment: @adadeh at the end.  It is always better to put the url yourself rather than depending on those global variables

Comment: possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262485/php-form-undefined-constant-php-self

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do not use any of the suggested versions of PHP_SELF. It is a **security nightmare**, opening up your PHP to a multitude of possible injection attacks.

What are you trying to achieve? Generate the URL for a form sending to itself? Use `action=""` for that - it is a valid approach and will always use the URL for sending the form as for loading.

If you must know the requested script, use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` instead.

Comment: I think it is better to play with the settings when learning in localhost and explore

Answer (score 14):

You are using `$PHP_SELF` it should be

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;
```

Or

```
$PHP_SELF = &$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo $PHP_SELF ;
```

You can also have

```
define("PHP_SELF",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
echo PHP_SELF ;
```

Comment: +1 @FirmView this one is for you `var_dump($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) // true `

Comment: It is OK
More references is better :)

Comment: For sanitizing the variable contents & making it more resilient to injection attacks I found this somewhere: `$PHP_SELF = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`. Using this in production has worked OK.

Comment: @DavidRamirez Your way is wrong, and your reasoning "it has worked ok" is flawed. In general PHP_SELF doesn't contain any characters that would be changed by `htmlentities()`, so it is natural that it works with positive cases. But you must want to have perfect protection against ANY attack - only making it "more resilient to injection attacks" simply isn't enough, these type of attack must be made completely impossible! And it is possible to do so, but it requires knowledge about how to correctly escape data - your solution isn't such.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to access $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like certain WordPress distributions declare `$PHP_SELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` for reasons I can't say, must be some sorta legacy thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have to Solve This Error Using Page Url...
Ex. Like

```
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 3 Records</a>";
```

You Have to remove $_PHP_SELF and use page URL
insert.php .......

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same,
Notice: Undefined variable _PHP_SELF
So I just replaced $_PHP_SELF to $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]
Now I don't get any extra no

Answer (score 0):

Some shells will erase the value of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` as a security measure. You may need to look at `$_SERVER['argv'][0]` if this is what is happening to you.

Answer (score -1):

I solved starting the variable:

```
$PHP_SELF = NULL;
$Path1 = realpath(substr($PHP_SELF, 1));
$dbName = "$Path1\\BD.accdb";
```