# Failure to display $result of a calculation

Tags: php

Here we are calculating a person's ideal weight **`($result)`** based off of their selected gender **`($gender)`** and their inputted height ($height).

For some reason, I am unable to see the echoed $result from the calculation.

Anyone have any clues as to why I cannot see this result?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$gender = $_POST['selectedGender'];
$height = $_POST['patientHeight'];
$result;
if ($gender == "Male") {
    $result = ($height * 4) - 128;
    echo $result; }           
else if ($gender == "Female") {    
    $result = ($height * 3.5) - 108;
    echo $result; }
}
?>
<html>
<div align="center">
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
    Select Your Gender: <select name="selectedGender">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    Enter Your Height: <input type="number" name="patientHeight" placeholder="Units are in Inches">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Calculate Your Ideal Weight"/>
</form>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: `name="patientheight"` vs `$_POST['patientHeight']`. notice the case of the `h` in `height`/`Height`?

Comment: @Sean edited, thank you! Still having a failure to display $result though. :(

Comment: Your code looks okay. Are you sure it is not echoing `$result` in the top left corner as you have it before your `<html><body>` tags? You might want to create a `div` inside your `body` to echo the result.

Comment: although `$PHP_SELF` should probably be `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710803/undefined-variable-php-self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `if / else if` isn't the best way to do this. You should be using a `switch/case` call.

```
switch($gender) {
    case "Male":
    $result = ($height * 4) - 128;
    break;
    case "Female":
    $result = ($height * 3.5) - 108;
    break;
    default:                         // notice the 'default' here?
    $result = 'derp';                // that will set it always.
    break;                           // meaning if you don't have a value present.
}
echo $result;
```

The above will cover all results, including the one where `$gender` isn't set.

As noted in other answers, there is no such variable called `$PHP_SELF`, you'll find that in server super global - `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that there is an empty radio button with the name `selectedGender`. If this is passed to the form, the if else if statement will not catch it, and not echo anything.

Maybe take out that empty radio button, or add a final `else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your echo is above `<html>`. This code will calculate the weight and render it in a javascript alert:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$gender = $_POST['selectedGender'];
$height = $_POST['patientHeight'];
$result;
if ($gender == "Male") { $result = ($height * 4) - 128; }           
else if ($gender == "Female") { $result = ($height * 3.5) - 108; }

    $msg = 'As a '.$gender.' '.$height.' inches tall your weight should be '.$result.' pounds.';
    echo '<Script language="javascript">alert("'.$msg.'");"</script>';
}
?>
```